# Cloth simulation pulling skirt upward

Tags: cloth-simulation

I wish I was joking. I have this skirt that I want to make it look more like a skirt using the cloth simulation thing but instead of pulling it downwards and giving it some folds, it pulls it upwards and is spiky. Using the cloth presets (silk, leather, etc) don't really change anything. I tried erasing the weight paint at the top and it still didn't work. 
I'm wondering if some of the settings I used is making it this way?

EDIT: Added screenshots of the geometry

[image: the skirt]

[image: cloth physics settings]

[image]

[image: geometry]

[image]

Comment: Most likely you have intersecting geometry at the start of the simulation or vert close vertices within the cloth that are repelling each other with the self collision. Can you share some images of your geometry in wireframe or Edit mode?

Comment: i added the screenshots!

Comment: Thanks. Try switching off Self Collision. If this doesn't help then scale up the mesh so it's definitely not intersecting with the model at the start of the simulation. You could also try reducing the cloth Speed Multiplier back down to one (it will produce a more stable simulation). There's a Self Collision Vertex Group that lets you exclude certain vertices from the 'self collision' group - it's a good idea to set that to the same as your 'Pinning' group. Could also try resetting all the cloth settings back to the defaults (those when you first add the cloth sim). Try changing one at a time.

Comment: ah, it worked! the skirt itself was colliding with the model at the start, so i'm assuming that was what made it all weird. I'm very new to this, so thank you for the help!

Comment: No worries - glad to help and glad it’s now working. I’ve added an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For cloth collision (and, indeed, any collision in Blender) it is important to ensure that the simulation starts *without* the meshes overlapping - otherwise they will instantly repel and can cause unpredicted results.

With cloth, if the ‘garments’ are intended to be quite tightly fitting you can use sewing springs or cloth shrinking to bring the garment together around the model once the simulation starts. Those options are found within the Cloth Sewing Springs panel.